# Restrict values in DataFrame to specified range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do I change values less than -3 to -3 and more than 1 to 1?

```
randomdata = DataFrame(np.random.randn(400, 4))
```

Comment: `how do i replace -3 to -3` What?

Comment: replace<-3 to -3 and <-1 to -1

Comment: See the answer below and mark it accepted if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, I think you're looking for `df.clip` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(400, 4)) 
df = df.clip(-3, 1)
```

And here's the numpy equivalent using `np.clip` -

```
df = np.clip(df, -3, 1)
```

Performance wise, they're almost identical, even for large data.